# How to change my reference movie's frame rate

Tags: animation

I try to make an animation so like a traditional animated. I import a reference video to blender. The problem is the video's frame rate is 50/s but my animation is 24/s. How to change the video's frame rate.[image]

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to add a **Video Editing workspace** side by side with your 3D view.  Obviously this is not quite as good as having an image as a plane movie, but would still give you a reference.

You would then drag the video footage onto the timeline.  You go to **Add, Effect Strip**, and add **Speed Control**.

Select the effect strip, then on the right side of the screen there is a control for the effect strip.  You will have to do a calculation to change the frame rate in the exact way you would like.

If I understand correctly:  Change it to "multiply",  check interpolation, and then you will enter the result of 50/24 which is 2.083 in that window to sync the video.  If this specific number doesn't work, try experimenting with the speed until you get the timing you want.
[image]